# Road bike disc wheel interchangability

Tags: road-bike, wheels, disc-brake

This may be a duplicate, but I didn't find an answer:

Are road bike disc wheelsets interchangable? For example my cx bike has DT Swiss R24 wheels, could I buy a set of Mavic Ksyrium wheels and fit them onto my bike? Thinking about it, the calliper is fixed onto the frame at a certain position, so I imagine this is possible, or is there something to watch out for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calliper and disc positions are standard, as are hub widths and fork spacings for disk wheels. Minor adjustments of the calliper's position could be required.
There are however several methods for locking the wheels in the fork that will require your attention: traditional quick release or different types of through axles!

Comment: Many are standardizing, but there is not one standard.  For example my 2006 cx bike has discs and is a QR setup, but and has a rear hub spacing of 130mm, while many modern QR disc road bikes have standardized at 135 mm.  Also I believe Specialized has there own SCS format, which will makes their road disc wheels incompatible with other frames (however some specialized frames can be adapted to non-SCS compliant wheels).  Most of these incompatibilities are due to different approaches taken for handling chain lines, chain stay lengths and Q-factors.

Comment: A 2006 CX was before the 135mm spacing came into general use for rear disk-brake-wheels on roadbikes.

Comment: 135mm coming into "general use" is exactly my point.  There are still edge cases out there (I presented two) so I don't think it is fair to claim there has been a complete shift to 135mm.  The OP explicitly asks about interchangeability, the OP would be left scratching their head if they came across some of the older "road disc" wheels at 130mm spacing or the specialized SCS wheels (if they had a thru axle setup).

Comment: Interesting. My DT Swiss wheels I quoted are 15x100 mm front and 12x142 mm rear. Checking on the Mavics, they specify 9x100 mm front and 10x135 mm. What would the few mm difference mean on the rear wheel?

Comment: @mogoman it would mean having to have a hub with convertible endcaps, or not being able to use that wheelset.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different sizes of rotor available. You'd obviously need to ensure you got the correct size of rotor for both sets of wheels.

Comment: Come one folks, I'm counting three downvotes and not one comment. You can do better than that, especially since this isn't even a wrong answer and does contribute a warning which addresses part of the answer.

Comment: Agreed. From my MTB I know that the rotor size is very important, thanks rob, important tip.